# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member images Arg_ParamName_Name'

Tags: object-detection, ml.net

private ITransformer SetupMlNetModel(IOnnxModel onnxModel)
{
var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List());

```
        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(resizing: 
            ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill, outputColumnName: onnxModel.ModelInput,     imageWidth: ImageSettings.imageWidth, imageHeight: ImageSettings.imageHeight, inputColumnName: nameof(ImageInputData.Image))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: onnxModel.ModelInput))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(modelFile: onnxModel.ModelPath, outputColumnName: onnxModel.ModelOutput, inputColumnName: onnxModel.ModelInput));

        var mlNetModel = pipeline.Fit(dataView);
```

``
return mlNetModel;
}